# Remove some leading part from a path in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have an absolute path set in `CW_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR`.
For example that could be `"/some/path/project"`.

Then I want to print `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`, but
without the leading `CW_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR` part.
For example, if `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is
`"/foo/bar/some/path/project/xyz"` then nothing should
be stripped off, but if it is `"/some/path/project/foo/bar"`
then just `"foo/bar"` should be printed.

How can I do this?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, that worked! `file(RELATIVE_PATH current_subdirectory "${CW_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract one path relative to another use [`file(RELATIVE_PATH <variable> <directory> <file>)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/file.html#relative-path).